# NullPointerException exception at Websphere?

Tags: java, servlets, websphere

I have servlet call to another servlet Using **PrintWriter** .Unable to redirect particular target URL.My code is

```
PrintWriter pw= null;
pw= response.getWriter();
pw.print("URL TO Redirect");
pw.close();
```

**Websphere  SystemErrorLog:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:485)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:301)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:275)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:557)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:607)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:984)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1069)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)
```

Comment: is it the same as http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM29501

Comment: Can you show a bit more code? What exactly is `response`?

Comment: @gaurav5430 , connection can be closed too early does it cause for this exception ??

Comment: @RyanCarlson see the link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg24020800

Answer (score 2):

`pw.close;` should be `pw.close();`.

Otherwise you're trying to access a non-private field, named `close`. And if such exists, it's possible it's `null`.

Apart from that, your code looks fine and the NPE reason is somewhere else.

Comment: connection can be closed too
early does it cause for this exception ? before request is complete we are closing the connection ...  see the link     http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg24020800